# When to use property of {silent : false|true} in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, fork, child-process, stdio

I am learning streams, child processes in Node.js, I am Windows user since childhood, had nothing to do with Unix/Linux nor C family lang, etc. which means I had none of conceptional knowledge before , so please no judge .

I faced and option of `{silent: boolean}` for child_process.**fork()** | (default: false)

> Note : **stdio array variant** overrides {silent : boolean}

**My question**: besides being overwritten , does any variant of **stdio** (shown in screenshotted table below) have some equivalent for silent property , if `property of silent` would be used instead of `stdio option` ?

AFAIK , fork()'s stdio: `[0,1,2, ipc]` should be equivalent of `{silent: true}` [[as answered hereby by Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478696/how-to-pass-messages-as-well-as-stdout-from-child-to-parent-in-node-js-child-pro)] , but keep in mind I may be mistaken so clarification would be highly appreciated !

| String | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `"ignore"` | `["ignore", "ignore", "ignore"]` |
| `"pipe"` | `["pipe", "pipe", "pipe"]` |
| `"inherit"` | `[process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]` or `[0, 1, 2]` |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `stdio` to `"pipe"` is equivalent to setting `silent` to `true`, and setting `stdio` to `"inherit"` is equivalent to setting `silent` to `false`.

Comment: I was close haha . Nevertheless appreciate a lot for editing & answering the question ! BTW, @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I've seen these days so many people getting disappointed that Node.js API refs may not , but Guides for sure are poorly documented : I 've tried many books on packt but I see that O'reilly is my last chance . Any unsolicited advice for resources to avoid hogging stack overflow with such questions in the future whatsoever ? Thank you .

Comment: @reposit96 When the documentation is insufficient, check the source instead. [That's what I did](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/340b770d3f4c3b50a5d36c0776afd63d9b4f22de/lib/child_process.js#L157-L158).